# Loading directory of JSON files takes much less time on 2nd run

Tags: python, json, io

I'm loading a directory of 3.7M JSON files on a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 server using Python. The strange thing is that the first time I run this simple script it takes multiple hours, whereas the second run only takes about 100 seconds. How can that be? Is the OS doing some kind of disk optimization in the background?

**Code**

```
parsed_links = {}
paths = glob.glob('parsed_links/*')

for i, p in enumerate(paths):
    try:
        with open(p, 'r') as f:
            parsed = json.load(f)
            parsed_links[parsed['link']] = parsed
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

Comment: diskcache maybe? running a process twice with various timings doesn't have anything to do with python. Not to mention that it's impossible to reproduce.

Comment: I think it could because of caching. If touching all the files again, the running time might go up significantly.

Comment: Okay. How do I keep them in cache for a specified amount of time? It's actually quite useful for debugging that the 2nd loading is so much faster.

Comment: Can I force Linux to cache all of the files before running the program?